# Descarga con filtros PHP

Tags: php, html

Quiero poder realizar una descarga con filtros. Hasta el momento logro que me descargue por ciudad, estado o por ciudad segun estado o viceversa, pero no que me descargue por un rango de fecha, o ciudad o estado segun fecha. En pocas palabras quiero descargar por un solo campo o por la combinación de todos los campos. El código que tengo es el siguiente.

**PHP**

```
$DESCARGAR = $_POST['descargar'];
$CIUDAD = $_POST['CIUDAD'];
$ESTADO = $_POST['ESTADO'];
$FECHA_DESDE = $_POST['FECHA_DESDE'];
$FECHA_HASTA = $_POST['FECHA_HASTA'];

if(isset($_POST['descargar'])) {

    if(empty($_POST['CIUDAD']))
    {
        $WHERE = "WHERE ESTADO = '".$ESTADO."'";
    }
    else if(empty($_POST['ESTADO']))
    {
        $WHERE = "WHERE CIUDAD = '".$CIUDAD."'";    
    }
    else if(empty($_POST['ESTADO']) && empty($_POST['CIUDAD']))
    {
        $WHERE = "WHERE FECHA_TANQUEO BETWEEN '".$FECHA_DESDE."' AND ".$FECHA_DESDE."'";    
    }
    else
    {
        $WHERE = "WHERE CIUDAD = '".$CIUDAD."' AND ESTADO = '".$ESTADO."'"; 
    }

}

$consulta= "SELECT * FROM combustible $WHERE";
$resultado= $mysqli->query($consulta);

header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=REPORTE DE COMBUSTIBLE ".$fecha.".xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

<?php
//Código para exportar a Excel, este código funciona correctamente
?>
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" name="FECHA_DESDE" id="FECHA_DESDE" class="tcal">
 <input type="text" name="FECHA_HASTA" id="FECHA_HASTA" class="tcal">

  <select name="CIUDAD" id="CIUDAD" >
    <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
    <option value="ARMENIA">ARMENIA</option>
    <option value="CALI">CALI</option>
  </select>

  <select name="ESTADO" id="ESTADO">
    <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
    <option value="PENDIENTE">PENDIENTE</option>
    <option value="RECIBIDO">RECIBIDO</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Cambiaría las sentencias `else if` por `if` y las querys las arreglaría de manera de que se puedan unir dinámicamente.
Crear un `where 1=1` y hacer las siguientes sentencias con `and`. Siendo así:
1.Sí no tengo ningún flltro (`select * from x where 1=1`) me trae todos. 2. Si tengo algún filtro (`select * from x where 1=1 and filtro`). 3 Si tengo 2 o más filtros  (`select * from x where 1=1 and filtro1 and filtro2`).

Comment: La manera correcta de resolver esto es usando consultas preparadas, que te protegerán de la inyección de código. De ese modo podrás crear una consulta dinámica según los filtros que sean y pasar los parámetros en un array. Si usas PDO será aún más fácil, ya que con mysqli, este tipo de manejos son ligeramente más complicados.

Comment: No hay forma de que se pueda realizar por el camino que voy, creí que solo tenia la sintaxis de los `empty` mal.

Comment: Hay forma, pero tu código tiene agujeros de seguridad. Si tú pasas una consulta así: `"SELECT * FROM combustible $WHERE"` al manejador de base de datos, por medio de la variable `$WHERE` se te pueden colar usuarios maliciosos, no sólo en la base de datos, sino hasta en el sistema... *MIENTRAS* tú ni te enteras, o te enteras demasiado tarde. Las consecuencias son variadas: desde borrar o alterar tablas, hasta colarte cualquier tipo de virus en el sistema.

Comment: Se que el que código es vulnerable a inyección SQL y otros errores de seguridad, pero por ahora no es algo de producción, si no que esta un localhost, así, que si puedes ayudarme de esta forma por el momento te lo agradecería @A.Cedano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veamos si esto te conviene.

El código tiene la siguiente lógica:

1. Usamos operadores ternarios para matar dos pájaros de un tiro: verificamos si el dato existe y si existe vamos construyendo criterios que luego pasaremos en el `WHERE`
2. Hacemos una evaluación más lógica de los posibles `WHERE`. No sé por qué te planteas una lógica algo enrevesada en el código de la pregunta. La lógica que he seguido es la siguiente: *si un valor existe en el `POST` es porque ese valor tiene que estar en el `WHERE`, punto*. En cuanto a las dos fechas, verifico que las dos tengan valores, si no, no creo el `WHERE` con el `BETWEEN`. Yo he asumido que los campos `CIUDAD` y `ESTADO` son del tipo `VARCHAR` u otro no numérico. Si son numéricos, debes quitar las comillas simples que encierran los criterios.
3. Al final usamos `implode` para crear todos los criterios, uniéndolos con `AND`.
4. Controla cómo tienes el bloque `if(isset($_POST['descargar'])) {`, el lanzamiento de la consulta no puede ir fuera de ese `if`.

Todo lo demás, dependerá de tu código.

Espero te sirva:

```
if(isset($_POST['descargar'])) {

    $arrWhere = [];
    $strWhere="";

    $strCiudad = empty($_POST['CIUDAD']) ? NULL : " CIUDAD='".$_POST['CIUDAD']."'";
    $strEstado = empty($_POST['ESTADO']) ? NULL : " ESTADO='".$_POST['ESTADO']."'";
    $strFechaDesde = empty($_POST['FECHA_DESDE']) ? NULL : " FECHA_TANQUEO BETWEEN '".$_POST['FECHA_DESDE']."'";
    $strFechaHasta = empty($_POST['FECHA_HASTA']) ? NULL : " AND '".$_POST['FECHA_HASTA']."'";

    if ($strCiudad)
    {
        $arrWhere[] = $strCiudad;
    }       
    if ($strEstado)
    {
        $arrWhere[] = $strEstado;
    }       
    if ($strFechaDesde && $strFechaHasta)
    {
        $arrWhere[] = $strFechaDesde.$strFechaHasta;
    }

    if ($arrWhere)
    {
        $strWhere=' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $arrWhere);
    }

    $strSQL= "SELECT * FROM combustible ".$strWhere;
    $resultado= $mysqli->query($strSQL);
    //Resto del código  

}else{

echo "No se pasó el POST descargar";

}
```

---

> **Nota:** La consulta `$strSQL= "SELECT * FROM combustible ".$strWhere;` no se debe pasar directamente al manejador de base de
>   datos, ya que la variable `$strWere` podría ser cambiada por código
>   dañino para la base de datos y para el sistema. El código se ha
>   escrito así únicamente para responder al problema concreto de los
>   criterios. No obstante, con PDO, este procedimiento sería **más seguro
>   y más fácil de realizar**.

Comment: Sigo sin poder imprimir un rango de fecha, no puedo descargar los datos que están entre las dos fechas seleccionadas.

Comment: @AnderssonViveros pero ¿existen datos con los criterios? (puede que no esté encontrando esos datos). Prueba a imprimir la variable: `$strSQL` con un `echo  $strSQL;`. De paso revisa si se está creando bien, cópiala y ejecútala en el manejador de base de datos a ver si arroja datos. Supongo que las columnas `FECHA_DESDE` y `FECHA_HASTA` son del tipo `DATETIME`.

Comment: Ya verifique y me arroja doble el `AND`

Comment: Ah claro, cambia esto: `$strFechaHasta = empty($_POST['FECHA_HASTA']) ? NULL : " AND '".$_POST['FECHA_HASTA']."'";` por esto: **`$strFechaHasta = empty($_POST['FECHA_HASTA']) ? NULL : "  '".$_POST['FECHA_HASTA']."'";`**

Comment: O puedes dejar esa parte así, y cambiar el penúltimo `if`, poniéndolo así: **`if ($strFechaDesde && $strFechaHasta)
    {
        $arrWhere[] = $strFechaDesde.$strFechaHasta;
    }`**, de ese modo el criterio se agregará como un solo criterio, no como dos, que luego podrían dar problemas en el `implode`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda